# program that returns a pointer to the character with the smallest ASCII value

Tags: c

I've written the following program

```
char *smallest_charachter(char str[]) {
    int * min = &str[0];
    int size = strlen(str);
    
    for (i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (str[i]<*min)
        {
            min = str[i];
        }
    }
    
    return min;
}
```

This function is meant to return a pointer to the character with the smallest ASCII value. After doing some testing, my function does not work properly and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Any hints or tips to fix my function would help a lot.

Comment: For starters: `int *min` should be `char *min`

Comment: On one line you have `min = &str[0]` and on another `min = str[i]`.  Notice the inconsistency?  Also, your compiler should have complained about that.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and ensure the code compiles without any warnings.

Comment: -Wall compiler argument should help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `strlen` if we make the `for` loop conditional into: `str[i]`

`min` should be `char *min` and *not* `int *min`.

You're confusing setup and test and set of `min`. In the loop, you set it from the character value when you should set it from the *address* of the value.

You don't define `i`.

Here's some refactored code:

```
char *
smallest_charachter(char str[])
{
    char *min = &str[0];

    for (int i = 1; str[i];  ++i) {
        if (str[i] < *min)
            min = &str[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```